# Calling Classes from another project in the same solution c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have two projects (1-Business: where I put the Linq Classes 2-View: wpf app, where i will show data) in the same solution (ProjectOne)
the problem is that I can't call the first project in the second one even when i add references (right click on the View project -->Property-->References Path-->Select the path of the Business Project Folder )

Comment: Why don't you add the reference by: right click on View project --> Add Reference --> browse and find Business project dll.
just to be more certain about the path being accurate!

Comment: it's the right solution thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact i found the solution,
 first of all change the output Type of the first project from  "Window Application" to "Class Library" and build it, then go to th the references of the second project and add the First one as a reference to it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a 'using' statement to the top of the class.

```
using ProjectOne.1-Business;

namespace ...
{
  public class ...
```

Comment: it doesn't recognize it

Comment: oops. forgot the main namespace

Answer (score 1):

always a good practice is cleaning the solution and then rebuilding it